# Diff with file titles printed out

Tags: shell, diff

I was wondering if there is way when the result is yelded from diff, to print the file names on top of the columns. 
Currently I get this ;

```
diff -a --suppress-common-lines -y output_main.txt output_compare.txt
XXX Version X.X(X)                                    | YYY Version Y.Y(Y)
 ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254               |  ip address 10.10.89.50 255.255.255.254
```

What would be helpful is something like :

```
 diff -a --suppress-common-lines -y output_main.txt output_compare.txt
    output_main.txt                                       output_compare.txt
========================                                  =======================
    XXX Version X.X(X)                                    | YYY Version Y.Y(Y)
     ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254               |  ip address 10.10.89.50 255.255.255.254
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. You'll have to print the header yourself: `ydiff(){ diff -I. -y <(printf "%s\n======\n" "$1") <(printf "%s\n======\n" "$2"); diff -y --suppress-common-lines -a "$@"; }`

Comment: Not possible with GNU diff; maybe other diff implementations offer an option for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's something similar to what you're asking for:

```
$ diff -c output_main.txt output_compare.txt
*** output_main.txt 2019-11-02 16:46:28.678377910 +0100
--- output_compare.txt  2019-11-02 16:46:27.770423548 +0100
***************
*** 1,2 ****
! XXX Version X.X(X)
!  ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254
--- 1,2 ----
! YYY Version Y.Y(Y)
!  ip address 10.10.89.50 255.255.255.254
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little weird but works like what you want...

```
$ diff -a -y --suppress-common-lines <(echo output_main.txt; cat output_main.txt) <(echo output_compare.txt; cat output_compare.txt) | sed 2i=============================================================================
output_main.txt                             |   output_compare.txt
===============================================================================
XXX Version X.X(X)                          |   YYY Version Y.Y(Y)
 ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254     |    ip address 10.10.89.50 255.255.255.254
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create new function:

```
mydiff(){
    printf '%.30s%65s\n' "$1" "$2" "================" "===================";
    command diff -y "$1" "$2"
}
```

The value `65` comes from the fact that

> The '--side-by-side' ('-y') option selects side by side format. 
>   Because side by side output lines contain two input lines, the output
>   is wider than usual: normally 130 print columns, which can fit onto a
>   traditional printer line.

You can change the columns width via `-W` option.

The output:

```
$ mydiff output_main.txt   output_compare.txt 

output_main.txt                                       output_compare.txt
================                                      ===================
XXX Version X.X(X)                                    | YYY Version Y.Y(Y)
 ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254               |  ip address 10.10.89.50 255.255.255.254
```

Comment: For a fun challenge, implement the column width calculation of diff into your function, so it could be used with other widths; with @sdp's solution, you just add eg `-W80` to both `diff` invocations.

Comment: [reference](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/diff.c?id=ee869b17b156400e1d76ea47aee35843d93d6908#n703)